# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in line 22

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have got this error on wordpress sites. I dont know how to fix it. Please help

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in
>   /home/hornyfus/public_html/wp-content/themes/wpxtubewhitetheme/header.php
>   on line 22

heres the line 22 in my head.php

```
echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s',d 'wpxtube_theme' ), max( $paged, $page ) ); ?></title>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
'Page %s',d 'wpxtube_theme'
```

Take out the `d`.